# Team Foundation Server reporting stops refreshing after adding a CMMi repository

Tags: sql-server-2005, sharepoint, tfs, cmmi

I have this problem and did not find in the site a case like mine.

Here is the thing.

I created a TFS 2008 with the scrum template (Conchango). It was a clean install (a fresh OS, a fresh SQL Server, a fresh machine, etc…). So everything worked like a charm.
I created 3 Scrum repositories, assigned permissions, uploaded files and so on… 3 teams started working on them, and everything was super!
Up to this point the server only had 3 scrum repositories and nothing else.

Then, I had to create a new repository, but with the CMMi template (the one provided with TFS).
Again everything works (the Sharepoint site, the source control, documents..) … BUT…. Reports stopped refreshing!!!

Does anybody know how to fix it?
Any help will be really appreciated

Should you need more info please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found someone with the same problem, reports do stop working after adding CMMI project :)

The following link has an explaination of how to fix it:

http://blog.salvoz.com/2008/01/26/TFSWarehouseIssues.aspx

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you didn't create a new repository. You created a new team project.

Secondly, the trick is to go find out why the reports stopped refreshing! There's no well-known bug, "reports stop refreshing when adding a CMMI Team Project: here's what to do". You'll need to go look on the database tier server and see if there are any problems listed in the event logs or the SQL Server logs. Then track it down.

I had one situation where Analysis Services crashed, restarted and crashed again - because I hadn't set up operator notification. It's necessary to look, in order to see.